# Custom camera preview stretched

Tags: android, android-camera, motorola

I have created custom camera (Compulsory in horizontal mode) to capture image.
But I'm getting problem in some devices like motorola g3 and g4, it works perfectly on samsung device.

Can some help to fix this.

Comment: what problem you are faced,please share code setting image to view

Comment: image preview is stretched on motorola devices, @sudo

Comment: do you use image view for show image ?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is at image preview screen when i open a custom camera, in that camera preview image get stretched

Comment: try android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: @sudo not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved above problem by creating custom activity file without xml,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Requires RelativeLayout.
    mLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    setContentView(mLayout);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Outter layout
    // Set the second argument by your choice.
    // Usually, 0 for back-facing camera, 1 for front-facing camera.
    // If the OS is pre-gingerbreak, this does not have any effect.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, 0, CameraPreview.LayoutMode.FitToParent);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams previewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mLayout.addView(mPreview, 0, previewLayoutParams);

    //Capture button
    captureButton = new Button(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    bParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    bParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    captureButton.setText("Capture");
    mLayout.addView(captureButton, bParams);

    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPreview.takePhoto();
        }
    });
}
```

Now create CameraPreview class

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private static boolean DEBUGGING = true;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "CameraPreviewSample";
private static final String CAMERA_PARAM_ORIENTATION = "orientation";
private static final String CAMERA_PARAM_LANDSCAPE = "landscape";
private static final String CAMERA_PARAM_PORTRAIT = "portrait";
protected Activity mActivity;
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
protected Camera mCamera;
protected List<Camera.Size> mPreviewSizeList;
protected List<Camera.Size> mPictureSizeList;
protected Camera.Size mPreviewSize;
protected Camera.Size mPictureSize;
private int mSurfaceChangedCallDepth = 0;
private int mCameraId;
private LayoutMode mLayoutMode;
private int mCenterPosX = -1;
private int mCenterPosY;
private CameraApp cameraApp;
private ImageCallback imageCallback;
private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
PreviewReadyCallback mPreviewReadyCallback = null;

public static enum LayoutMode {
    FitToParent, // Scale to the size that no side is larger than the parent
    NoBlank // Scale to the size that no side is smaller than the parent
};

public interface PreviewReadyCallback {
    public void onPreviewReady();
}

/**
 * State flag: true when surface's layout size is set and surfaceChanged()
 * process has not been completed.
 */
protected boolean mSurfaceConfiguring = false;

public CameraPreview(Activity activity, int cameraId, LayoutMode mode) {
    super(activity); // Always necessary
    mActivity = activity;
    mLayoutMode = mode;
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > cameraId) {
            mCameraId = cameraId;
        } else {
            mCameraId = 0;
        }
    } else {
        mCameraId = 0;
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        mCamera = Camera.open(mCameraId);
    } else {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
    }
    mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Camera.Parameters cameraParams = mCamera.getParameters();
    mPreviewSizeList = cameraParams.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    mPictureSizeList = cameraParams.getSupportedPictureSizes();
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    mSurfaceChangedCallDepth++;
    doSurfaceChanged(width, height);
    mSurfaceChangedCallDepth--;
}

private void doSurfaceChanged(int width, int height) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();

    Camera.Parameters cameraParams = mCamera.getParameters();
    boolean portrait = isPortrait();

    // The code in this if-statement is prevented from executed again when surfaceChanged is
    // called again due to the change of the layout size in this if-statement.
    if (!mSurfaceConfiguring) {
        Camera.Size previewSize = determinePreviewSize(portrait, width, height);
        Camera.Size pictureSize = determinePictureSize(previewSize);
        if (DEBUGGING) { Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Desired Preview Size - w: " + width + ", h: " + height); }
        mPreviewSize = previewSize;
        mPictureSize = pictureSize;
        mSurfaceConfiguring = adjustSurfaceLayoutSize(previewSize, portrait, width, height);
        // Continue executing this method if this method is called recursively.
        // Recursive call of surfaceChanged is very special case, which is a path from
        // the catch clause at the end of this method.
        // The later part of this method should be executed as well in the recursive
        // invocation of this method, because the layout change made in this recursive
        // call will not trigger another invocation of this method.
        if (mSurfaceConfiguring && (mSurfaceChangedCallDepth <= 1)) {
            return;
        }
    }

    configureCameraParameters(cameraParams, portrait);
    mSurfaceConfiguring = false;

    try {
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Failed to start preview: " + e.getMessage());

        // Remove failed size
        mPreviewSizeList.remove(mPreviewSize);
        mPreviewSize = null;

        // Reconfigure
        if (mPreviewSizeList.size() > 0) { // prevent infinite loop
            surfaceChanged(null, 0, width, height);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Can't start preview", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Gave up starting preview");
        }
    }

    if (null != mPreviewReadyCallback) {
        mPreviewReadyCallback.onPreviewReady();
    }
}

/**
 * @param portrait
 * @param reqWidth must be the value of the parameter passed in surfaceChanged
 * @param reqHeight must be the value of the parameter passed in surfaceChanged
 * @return Camera.Size object that is an element of the list returned from Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes.
 */
protected Camera.Size determinePreviewSize(boolean portrait, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Meaning of width and height is switched for preview when portrait,
    // while it is the same as user's view for surface and metrics.
    // That is, width must always be larger than height for setPreviewSize.
    int reqPreviewWidth; // requested width in terms of camera hardware
    int reqPreviewHeight; // requested height in terms of camera hardware
    if (portrait) {
        reqPreviewWidth = reqHeight;
        reqPreviewHeight = reqWidth;
    } else {
        reqPreviewWidth = reqWidth;
        reqPreviewHeight = reqHeight;
    }

    if (DEBUGGING) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Listing all supported preview sizes");
        for (Camera.Size size : mPreviewSizeList) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "  w: " + size.width + ", h: " + size.height);
        }
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Listing all supported picture sizes");
        for (Camera.Size size : mPictureSizeList) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "  w: " + size.width + ", h: " + size.height);
        }
    }

    // Adjust surface size with the closest aspect-ratio
    float reqRatio = ((float) reqPreviewWidth) / reqPreviewHeight;
    float curRatio, deltaRatio;
    float deltaRatioMin = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    Camera.Size retSize = null;
    for (Camera.Size size : mPreviewSizeList) {
        curRatio = ((float) size.width) / size.height;
        deltaRatio = Math.abs(reqRatio - curRatio);
        if (deltaRatio < deltaRatioMin) {
            deltaRatioMin = deltaRatio;
            retSize = size;
        }
    }

    return retSize;
}

protected Camera.Size determinePictureSize(Camera.Size previewSize) {
    Camera.Size retSize = null;
    for (Camera.Size size : mPictureSizeList) {
        if (size.equals(previewSize)) {
            return size;
        }
    }

    if (DEBUGGING) { Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Same picture size not found."); }

    // if the preview size is not supported as a picture size
    float reqRatio = ((float) previewSize.width) / previewSize.height;
    float curRatio, deltaRatio;
    float deltaRatioMin = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    for (Camera.Size size : mPictureSizeList) {
        curRatio = ((float) size.width) / size.height;
        deltaRatio = Math.abs(reqRatio - curRatio);
        if (deltaRatio < deltaRatioMin) {
            deltaRatioMin = deltaRatio;
            retSize = size;
        }
    }

    return retSize;
}

protected boolean adjustSurfaceLayoutSize(Camera.Size previewSize, boolean portrait,
        int availableWidth, int availableHeight) {
    float tmpLayoutHeight, tmpLayoutWidth;
    if (portrait) {
        tmpLayoutHeight = previewSize.width;
        tmpLayoutWidth = previewSize.height;
    } else {
        tmpLayoutHeight = previewSize.height;
        tmpLayoutWidth = previewSize.width;
    }

    float factH, factW, fact;
    factH = availableHeight / tmpLayoutHeight;
    factW = availableWidth / tmpLayoutWidth;
    if (mLayoutMode == LayoutMode.FitToParent) {
        // Select smaller factor, because the surface cannot be set to the size larger than display metrics.
        if (factH < factW) {
            fact = factH;
        } else {
            fact = factW;
        }
    } else {
        if (factH < factW) {
            fact = factW;
        } else {
            fact = factH;
        }
    }

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)this.getLayoutParams();

    int layoutHeight = (int) (tmpLayoutHeight * fact);
    int layoutWidth = (int) (tmpLayoutWidth * fact);
    if (DEBUGGING) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Preview Layout Size - w: " + layoutWidth + ", h: " + layoutHeight);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Scale factor: " + fact);
    }

    boolean layoutChanged;
    if ((layoutWidth != this.getWidth()) || (layoutHeight != this.getHeight())) {
        layoutParams.height = layoutHeight;
        layoutParams.width = layoutWidth;
        if (mCenterPosX >= 0) {
            layoutParams.topMargin = mCenterPosY - (layoutHeight / 2);
            layoutParams.leftMargin = mCenterPosX - (layoutWidth / 2);
        }
        this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); // this will trigger another surfaceChanged invocation.
        layoutChanged = true;
    } else {
        layoutChanged = false;
    }

    return layoutChanged;
}

/**
 * @param x X coordinate of center position on the screen. Set to negative value to unset.
 * @param y Y coordinate of center position on the screen.
 */
public void setCenterPosition(int x, int y) {
    mCenterPosX = x;
    mCenterPosY = y;
}

protected void configureCameraParameters(Camera.Parameters cameraParams, boolean portrait) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) { // for 2.1 and before
        if (portrait) {
            //cameraParams.set(CAMERA_PARAM_ORIENTATION, CAMERA_PARAM_PORTRAIT);
            cameraParams.set(CAMERA_PARAM_ORIENTATION, CAMERA_PARAM_LANDSCAPE);
        } else {
            cameraParams.set(CAMERA_PARAM_ORIENTATION, CAMERA_PARAM_LANDSCAPE);
        }
    } else { // for 2.2 and later
        int angle;
        Display display = mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        switch (display.getRotation()) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0: // This is display orientation
                angle = 90; // This is camera orientation
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                angle = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                angle = 270;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                angle = 180;
                break;
            default:
                angle = 90;
                break;
        }
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "angle: " + angle);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(angle);
    }

    cameraParams.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
    cameraParams.setPictureSize(mPictureSize.width, mPictureSize.height);
    if (DEBUGGING) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Preview Actual Size - w: " + mPreviewSize.width + ", h: " + mPreviewSize.height);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Picture Actual Size - w: " + mPictureSize.width + ", h: " + mPictureSize.height);
    }

    if (cameraParams.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO)) {
        cameraParams.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
    }

    mCamera.setParameters(cameraParams);
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    stop();
}

public void stop() {
    if (null == mCamera) {
        return;
    }
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
}

public boolean isPortrait() {
    return (mActivity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}

public void setOneShotPreviewCallback(PreviewCallback callback) {
    if (null == mCamera) {
        return;
    }
    mCamera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(callback);
}

public void setPreviewCallback(PreviewCallback callback) {
    if (null == mCamera) {
        return;
    }
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(callback);
}

public Camera.Size getPreviewSize() {
    return mPreviewSize;
}

public void setOnPreviewReady(PreviewReadyCallback cb) {
    mPreviewReadyCallback = cb;
}

public void takePhoto(){
    if(mCamera != null){
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
                if(bytes.length > 0){
                    Log.d("CameraPreview","Yes!!! We got an Image");
                }
                Bitmap capturedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                //capturedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(capturedBitmap,1196,527,true);
                imageCallback = (ImageCallback) mActivity;
                imageCallback.resultImage(capturedBitmap);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thats it !!, you are almost done
Just one more thing that you need to create, is interface for getting result in your main activity.
Pls. feel free to ask your query.

Comment: Done, thanq bro
one more question, how to convert bitmap to uri or image file

Answer (score 0):

Use property android:adjustViewBounds="true"

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: The issue is not related to image after clicked, is regarding image preview.. i mean when we open an camera app we see some objects on screen .. on that screen preview is starched